# SSRS 2012 Report Builder 3.0 Bar and Point on Same Chart

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I would like to add points to a stacked column chart as per the attached image[image: spine chart image]. I am able to do this in Excel by changing the data series type for the points to x-y scatter. However in report builder when highlight a series and select change chart type it changes the type for all the series on the chart.
Any ideas on how I might achieve this would be much appreciated.

Comment: Hm.. I just did something similar on a report I built and I did what you did, just changed the chart type of that series.  I was using a 2014 SSRS instance so maybe that's the difference?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49113985/in-report-builder-3-0-is-it-possible-to-have-a-chart-where-some-elements-are-sta

Comment: Maybe it is the version as I've see a youtube clip of someone changing the chart type for one series but it won't do it in my version without changing the type for all series.

Comment: I also tried in visual studio 2010 and found the same problem. Unfortunately we're limited to the versions provided by our IT department and therefore cannot upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the logic between Excel and SSRS are different. The issue seems to be that SSRS says the two chart types are incompatible.

When I try to do it in SSRS 2014, instead of changing one series, it changes them both without giving an error or any other message.

When I hit UNDO and then REDO, it gives an error message. (*But it WAD* - MS)

[image]

The issue seems to be that the Axis of the bar chart doesn't work with the axis from the scatter - probably since the bar chart is one dimensional but the scatter is two.

It does seem to work with a Stacked Bar Chart. Could you use that instead? Make sure you change the Horizontal Axis of the Scatter to Secondary.

[MSDN - Multiple Series on a Chart](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-design/multiple-series-on-a-chart-report-builder-and-ssrs?view=sql-server-2017)

[image]

Comment: Hi Thanks for looking at this. I also get the error on undo. Having tried a stacked column (vertical bars) it lets me change one of the series to scatter (both axis set to secondary). However, if I select stacked bar (horizontal bars), it changes all series to stacked bar and won't let me change the individual series back to scatter without automatically changing all the series to scatter.